# how to get values from script element

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

want to get some values from html script element with HTML Agility

Need to output these values : "KMN Gang Azet T-Shirt Fast" and "https://www.30grad.shop/item/images/11296/3000x3000/azet-kmngang-shirt-fastlife.jpg"

I already got the script element but can't get the values.

```
  (function(){var pinto_primary_url='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.il.en_US.mTcJQn619Nc.O/m\x3dcdos,r,jsa,csi,dbm,cr,d,ivg,dgm,ish,qtf,ivw/am\x3dAACYGj0C/rt\x3dj/d\x3d1/t\x3dzcms/rs\x3dACT90oERgo7cd2pKPZNXIWg1CpAwZ14CoQ';var _expids='201794,1354277,1354722,1354916,1355527,1355736,1355922,1356032,1356078,1356343,1356470,1356555,4029815,4031109,4038214,4038394,4041776,4043492,4045096,4045293,4045841,4047140,4047454,4048347,4048980,4050750,4051887,4056126,4056682,4058016,4061666,4061980,4062724,4064468,4064796,4069829,4076999,4078430,4078588,4080760,4081039,4081165,4082230,4083113,4097153,4097922,4097929,4098733,4098740,4098752,4102238,4103474,4103845,4103861,4104202,4104258,4106085,4106647,4109293,4109316,4109490,4110086,4110931,4112243,4113217,4115289,4115624,4115697,4116349,4116724,4116731,4116926,4116935,4117328,4117980,4118227,4118798,4119032,4119034,4119036,4120415,4120660,4120911,4121035,4121518,4122382,4123645,4124091,4124850,4125837,4126200,4127095,4127445,4127744,4128586,4129001,4129002,4129555,4129559,4129633,4130362,4130560,4131073,4131247,4131370,4131834,4132528,4132785,4132956,4133063,4133064,4133090,4133114,4133416,4133755,4134271,4134919,4134946,4135085,4135089,4135249,4135404,4135576,4135744,4135934,4136073,4136235,4136562,4136627,4137099,4137110,4137415,4137461,4137462,4137597,4137646,4138341,4138344,4138431,4138853,4139394,4139435,4139701,4139928,4140117,4140241,4140464,4140786,4140798,4141393,4141520,4141581,4141683,4141725,4141729,4142231,4142326,4142328,4142420,4142492,4142494,4142503,4142504,4142558,4142560,4142574,4142607,4142610,4142729,4143112,4143132,4143224,4143246,4143318,4143578,10200083,10202524,10202535,10202543,10202562,41317155';var pinto_module_config='{\x22/1S6iw\x22:{},\x2210Kacw\x22:{},\x22ADSBcg\x22:{},\x22Fa+7Pw\x22:{},\x22NpA8BQ\x22:{},\x22WZXAwQ\x22:{},\x22YFCs/g\x22:{},\x22aWiv7g\x22:{},\x22cdos\x22:{\x22bih\x22:877,\x22biw\x22:1760,\x22cdobsel\x22:false,\x22dpr\x22:\x221\x22},\x22cr\x22:{\x22eup\x22:false,\x22qir\x22:false,\x22rctj\x22:true,\x22ref\x22:false,\x22uff\x22:false},\x22csi\x22:{\x22acsi\x22:true,\x22dlm\x22:true,\x22jsmf\x22:true},\x22d\x22:{},\x22gf\x22:{\x22pid\x22:196},\x22hmvvig\x22:{},\x22jsa\x22:{\x22csi\x22:true,\x22csir\x22:100},\x22r\x22:{},\x22sx\x22:{},\x22v0BWCA\x22:{}}';var ctx=["root",[["t-a2hICACK35I","is_NJKM1C840","r-is_NJKM1C840",[["global_config",null,null,null,null,[null,"[\"AOvVaw3piykki21tcS6pJhxrjznh\\u0026ust\\u003d1511885221974957\",null,0,null,0,null,null,null,0,null,null,null,1,1,1,1,0,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,0,0,null,null,null,0,null,null,0,0,null,null,1,null,400,null,null,null,1,null,0,null,null,null,null,0,0,\"NONE\",null,4,\"Related image\",7,0,\"%1$d\\u0026nbsp;\\u0026#215;\\u0026nbsp;%2$d\",0,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,\"#222\",0,1,null,1,null,0,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,0]\n"]
]
,["group_config",null,null,null,null,[null,"[null,null,null,null,1,null,null,1]\n"]
]
,["image_group",null,null,null,null,[null,"[[[0,\"mdba4buxuK9BKM:\",[\"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q\\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRR2V_IL-Zh_LdrVzgBgvq6zcL68YSL01zNGsQJxXTo2cpXaqVz6A\",256,197]\n,[\"https://www.30grad.shop/item/images/11296/3000x3000/azet-kmngang-shirt-fastlife.jpg\",3000,2315]\n,null,0,{\"2001\":[]\n,\"2003\":[null,\"RXXHApKYqqq7RM\",\"https://www.30grad.shop/hersteller/kmn-gang/\",\"KMN Gang | 30° Shop\",\"KMN Gang Azet T-Shirt Fast Life\",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,\"30° Merchandise Shop\"]\n}]\n]\n]\n"]
]
]
]
,["t-cuCqGEujB5w","ik5Gk2IHW4Sw","r-ik5Gk2IHW4Sw",[["enable_close_for_background",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,1]
]
,["initial_open",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,null,0]
]
,["remain_in_lightbox_container",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,0]
]
,["ux",null,null,null,null,[null,"[{\"220802553\":1}]\n"]
]
,["gsa",null,null,null,null,[null,"[{\"46740956\":0,\"244399487\":0}]\n"]
]
]
]
,["t-RHI35lUscno","iIJTpCvJ03LA","r-iIJTpCvJ03LA"]
,["t-3mFqq0A9uuY","iy1_jPBsPPco","r-iy1_jPBsPPco",[["hide_label_on_focus",null,null,null,null,[null,null,null,null,0]
]
]
]
,["t-mqWFpp0vPaI","i7Nj7DN5Ak3M","r-i7Nj7DN5Ak3M"]
,["t-mqWFpp0vPaI","i_DjAejc9SK4","r-i_DjAejc9SK4"]
,["t-mqWFpp0vPaI","iUYK6IKmz8Cg","r-iUYK6IKmz8Cg"]
]
]
;window._ = this;window._DumpException = function(e){throw e;};google.xjsu = pinto_primary_url;google.kEXPI = _expids;google.pmc = JSON.parse(pinto_module_config);google.jsc.x(ctx);})();
```

C# code

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(pagesourceCode);

        var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");
```

Comment: Format that array code properly. My eyes are on the verge of bleeding.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't access Javascript code using Html Agility pack. It's for HTML itself.

In fact, let me rephrase it, you can access the body of a javascript which is enclosed in `<script>` tags, but you will not mine that data out of it as you have it.

You would probably need to serialize the object by stripping the function and variable declarations as then you'll be able to treat it as JSON. Alternatively you can use regex... but good luck with that with the provided structure.